# After clicking the submit button stop fields from getting clear

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to php I am trying to stop field from getting clear after I hit the submit button also I want create Reset button which can clear the fields when needed. I hope it make sense here is the code, and please describe how you solved it thanks:

```
<?php
$result = "";
 class calculator
{
var $a;
var $b;

function checkopration($oprator)
{
    switch($oprator)
    {
        case '+':
        return $this->a + $this->b;
        break;

        case '-':
        return $this->a - $this->b;
        break;

        case '*':
        return $this->a * $this->b;
        break;

        case '/':
        return $this->a / $this->b;
        break;

        default:
        return "Sorry No command found";
    }
}
function getresult($a, $b, $c)
{
    $this->a = $a;
    $this->b = $b;
    return $this->checkopration($c);
}
}

$cal = new calculator();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $result = $cal->getresult($_POST['n1'],$_POST['n2'],$_POST['op']);
}
?>

  <form method="post">
  <table align="center">
     <tr>
       <td><strong><?php echo $result; ?><strong></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
          <td>Enter 1st Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="n1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Enter 2nd Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="n2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select Oprator</td>
    <td><select name="op">
        <option value="+">+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="*">*</option>
        <option value="/">/</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="                =                "></td>
</tr>

 </table>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a little bit and added a javascript function that will clear any element that you give the classname `clearOnReset`

```
<form method="post">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td><strong class="clearOnReset"><?php echo $result; ?></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enter 1st Number</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="n1" class="clearOnReset" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['n1'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['n1']);}?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enter 2nd Number</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="n2" class="clearOnReset" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['n2'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['n2']);}?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Select Oprator</td>
      <td>
        <select name="op">
          <option value="+" <?php if(isset($_POST['op']) && $_POST['op']=="+") { echo "selected";}?>>+</option>
          <option value="-" <?php if(isset($_POST['op']) && $_POST['op']=="-") { echo "selected";}?>>-</option>
          <option value="*" <?php if(isset($_POST['op']) && $_POST['op']=="*") { echo "selected";}?>>*</option>
          <option value="/" <?php if(isset($_POST['op']) && $_POST['op']=="/") { echo "selected";}?>>/</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="                =                ">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<button onclick="resetCalculator()">reset calculator</button>
<script>
function resetCalculator(){
    var fieldsToClear = document.getElementsByClassName("clearOnReset");
    for(var i = 0; i < fieldsToClear.length; i++){
        fieldsToClear[i].value="";
    }
}
</script>
```

All the javascript function does is that it finds all elements with the class name`clearOnReset` then places them into an array called `fieldsToClear` The line below that one then goes through every element in that array and sets its value to `""` which is essentially nothing.

The php code ive added checks if certain post request parameters have been set and if so places them in their respective locations in the form

If you still have any questions or notice any problems with my code feel free to write a comment below this answer.

Comment: Fields are automatically getting clear when hit submit button. That is actually the main issue

Comment: Ok so i seem to have misread your question, check back in 5 minutes and ill have edited my answer

Comment: for example if you enter 4 in field n1 and 5 in field n2 and click on submit button the 4 and 5 disappear from the fields and i am left with the answer 9. I dont want them to go. So what I am trying is when I hit the reset button atleast It should set n1 and n2 to 0. If not retain the actual value  which was 4 and 5.

Comment: I have made an edit to my code, please attempt to run it and get back to me

Comment: I made some changes to the code that you gave and it worked thanks bro

Comment: Next, I am trying to make an error if someone puts an alphabet in the field instead of number. Let me know how to do that if you know.

Comment: no problem, just noticed what i did wrong and made the edit, please upvote if this answer has helped you and please create a new question for your next question, feel free to comment a link here to your next question so i can take a look at it

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote you . though I accepted your answer. Also here is the link to the question. I kept the code same as I already had it formated. Thanks again    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265120/php-error-message-on-invalid-input

Answer (score 0):

At first U have to add jquery library file and add id to the reset button as the name reset.
then

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#reset").click(function(){
            $("input[type='text']").val('');
        })
    })
```

Comment: Do u add jquery library file ?

Comment: Yeah I imported it <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">

Comment: Sorry, i got it wrong ! see the update .Hope it will be ok